# g++ compile using custom header file

Tags: c++, g++

I want to use a header file,
its included as `#include <custom.h>`

how can I compile it by using the custom.h header file ?

I tried `-I /path/to/custom.h` , but its giving me error that its not a directory..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-I /path/to
```

This will enable all headers in that directory to be found.

In man gcc, search (using / in your pager) for "-I dir":

> #### -I dir
>
> Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files.  Directories named by -I are searched before the standard system include directories.  If the directory dir is a standard system include directory, the option is ignored to ensure that the default search order for system directories and the special treatment of system headers are not defeated.  If dir begins with "=", then the "=" will be replaced by the sysroot prefix; see --sysroot and -isysroot.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `/path/to/custom.h` is not a directory but a file.

```
-I/path/to/custom/
```

Comment: Roger is right. The directory is /path/to, not /path/to/custom

Comment: @Martin Are you serious ?? I see you know the computer of Krishna perfectly well.

Comment: He said he tried /path/to/custom.h, so /path/to surely must be the directly where custom.h is located... I know that this is just a place holder, but it helps understanding to assume that this would be the actual value. Otherwise, he might infer that he has to drop the .h from the file name for the -I option, and add a slash - he clearly didn't know that you are supposed to give directories to -I.